# need help interpreting 2016-08-04T00:02:10-04:00

Tags: date, date-format

have difficulty figuring out what the -04:00 towards the end might represent. any help will be highly appreciated.
I have a dataset that contains dates in the format '2016-08-04T00:02:10-04:00' while i know the date and time component i do not understand what the -04:00 does

Answer (score 2):

This is a universal date format according to ISO_8601. The -04:00 actually indicates the timezone

For more information see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: In particular the following section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC

Comment: More precisely: `-04:00` indicates an *offset* from UTC (or GMT). It’s not the same as a time zone. A time zone is a place on earth (hence the name) and the historical and known future changes to UTC offset in that place. `-04:00` isn’t that. A time zone is conventionally indicated as America/Montreal or Asia/Tokyo, for example (generally named after largest city or town in the zone).